# keep the value of variables after removing forms or elements javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, reload

I am creating a script with the following behavior:

1. load a video
2. show some comments and instructions after the first video ends
3. repeat this

To achieve this I have a `div`, and there the video is loaded then removed, then the next element is shown and removed. As you can imagine there is an array of each element to display, and the array is handled by an index. 
Actually the page is reloaded even if the form is NOT deleted is also not related with submit action, I have changed to a button to avoid it. The reloading happens when the next video is loaded. Any help will be appretiated

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Bacteriología</title>
</head>

<body>
 <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

 <script>

var preguntas=["De que trata la Bacteriología Diagnóstica?", 
"Cuales son las Bacterias Procariotas?", 
"no se",
"pero no importa"];
var movies=["../Bacteriologia/BactDiagDia1Parte1v.mp4","../Bacteriologia/BactDiagDia1Parte1.mp4","../Bacteriologia/BactDiagDiagParte11a.mp4","../Bacteriologia/BactDiagD1Parte 1_2a.mp4","../Bacteriologia/BacteiagD1 Parte 1_3a.mp4"];
var indexm=0;
var amovie=[0,0,1,2];
var apreg=[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]; //opciones asociadas a preguntas

var opciones=["de la vida y del amor","de la ausencia y de ti","de bacterias, microbios, y protozaurios","uno","dos","tres","unopp","dospp","trespp",
    "unop","dosp","tresp","cuatrop"]

var movieactual=0;

function botonValidation(){
    alert("en BVal"+movieactual);
     mform=document.getElementById('newForm');
     mform.parentNode.removeChild(mform);
    };

function displayQButton(){
    var i, j;
    $form = $("<form></form>");
    $form.attr('id', 'newForm');
    $form.appendTo('#miArea');
    for (i=0;i<apreg.length;i++) {
        if (apreg[i]==movieactual){
          nombre="boxCount"+i; 
         $('#newForm').append(opciones[i]);
          var radioBtn = $('<input type="checkbox" name=nombre />');;          
          radioBtn.appendTo('#newForm'); 
          var newElem = document.createElement("BR");
          $('#newForm').append(newElem);
         }
    }
    $form.append('<button onclick="botonValidation()">Sendme please</button>'); 
    event.stopEvent();      
  //endofdisplayQuestion
}

function deleteVideo(id) {
    Video=document.getElementById(id);
    Video.parentNode.removeChild(Video);
    alert("Video");
}//end of deleteVideo()

function loadVideo(nombre,id) {
    mypara=document.getElementById("miArea");
    var videlem = document.createElement("video");
    videlem.id=id;
    videlem.width="640"; 
    videlem.height="480";
    videlem.controls="controls";
    videlem.setAttribute("onended", "videoEnded()");
    videlem.setAttribute ("autoplay","autoplay");
    var sourceMP4 = document.createElement("source"); 
    sourceMP4.type = "video/mp4";
    sourceMP4.src = nombre;
    videlem.appendChild(sourceMP4);
    mypara.appendChild(videlem);
}

function videoEnded() {
    deleteVideo("video");
    movieactual=movieactual+1;
    movie=movies[movieactual];
    displayQButton();
    alert(movieactual); 

    loadVideo(movie,"video");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Loading Page;"+movieactual);
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {  
        movie=movies[movieactual];
        loadVideo(movie,"video");
    } else { alert ("Por favor actualice su browser ");}
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="miArea">
<form></form></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the actual code, but removing a DOM element should not cause a page reload, unless that is implicit in the code logic. The first thing I'd figure out is why the page reloads if you don't expect it to. If you do expect it to then know how to differentiate between the page reloading due to removing the form and a first load (you can do this by saving values in localStorage)

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Nobody can help when you don't post the relevant code

Comment: Thanks for the comment, a qq while I post the code, obviously the form has elements on it, do I need to remove element by element instead of removing the whole form?

Comment: function deleteVideo(id) {
 Video=document.getElementById(id);
 Video.parentNode.removeChild(Video);
//   $('#miArea').remove('video');
}//end of deleteVideo()

Comment: function RadioValidation(){
         alert("Aqui Radio validation");
//    $('#newForm').remove();
   forma=document.getElementById("newForm");
         forma.parentNode.removeChild(forma);};

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 movieprov=globals.MOVIE_ACTUAL;
    globals.MOVIE_ACTUAL=movieprov+1;
 alert(globals.MOVIE_ACTUAL);
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") { // Code for localStorage/localStorage. 
      if (localStorage.movieactual) {localStorage.movieactual = Number(localStorage.movieactual)+1;
  if (localStorage.movieactual>=movies.length){localStorage.movieactual=0;}
      } else {
            localStorage.movieactual = 0;
        }
  movie=movies[localStorage.movieactual];
      loadVideo(movie,"video");
    } else { alert (" actualice su browser ");}
});

Comment: sorry, i couldn't find a way to post the whole code.

Comment: I am checking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx and it states that the page will be unloaded when "Submit a form to the address specified in the ACTION attribute via the INPUT type=submit control, or invoke the form.submit method."

Comment: How can I prevent this behavior when I submit the form?